# Add field to django admin

Tags: python, django, admin

So I'm using this [custom user](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user) to replace the default login with username by email.

But I still want my user to have an username so I've done what they say in the doc. But in my admin, when I want to create or update my user I've not the field "username".

Here is my code.

models:

```
from django.db import models
from custom_user.models import AbstractEmailUser

class Account(AbstractEmailUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
```

admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from custom_user.admin import EmailUserAdmin
from authentication.models import Account


class AccountAdmin(EmailUserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'username')
    # fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')


admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
```

I've try to put the fields thing but I've got the following error.

ERRORS:
: (admin.E005) Both 'fieldsets' and 'fields' are specified.

I'm using python 3.4 and django 1.8

Answer (score 3):

Your `EmailUserAdmin` probably already defines `fieldsets`.

Look at the definition of `EmailUserAdmin`, and declare `fieldsets` in `AccountAdmin` accordingly, instead of using `fields`.

You'll probably want to keep the [documentation on `fieldsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) handy.

Comment: Yes but it's a package that i've installed. I don't know where is the code.  Can I just surcharge it?

Comment: @eiffelPower You cannot surcharge `fieldsets`, you have to redefine it entirely. Just running `print(EmailUserAdmin.fieldsets)` (with the appropriate imports) from the django shell should give you the definition, though.

Answer (score 0):

In `class AccountAdmin(EmailUserAdmin)` add the following `fieldsets = None`.